# Bitnami Django - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, bitnami, django-cors-headers

I have installed Django(Shopify app) on AWS using bitnami. Everything is working fine but when I send xmlhttp request from Shopify store to Django I get CORS error-

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://django-app-url' from origin
>   'https://store_url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have enabled cors on django- as earlier I was using openlite on aws and it was working.
After moving to bitnami i started getting error-

cors headers installed-

```
pip3 install django-cors-headers
```

and cors headers added in settings.py in middleware and installed apps

Also added in `/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/conf httpd.conf`

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: Did you include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` line inside the Directory block? I just checked the response headers in the browser and it included the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` value in the list. Can you verify that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your settings.py. Hope it will work.

I face the same issue and after adding these settings the issue was fixed!

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:4200',
    'localhost:8000',
    '127.0.0.1:8000',
    ...
)

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = (
    '127.0.0.1:9200',
    ....
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```

Comment: I modified settings.py and restarted apache but still no luck. I am facing this issue with bitnami only so may be its not django settings.

Comment: `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True  
   
ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS = True   

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True   
  
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['www.movri.ca','movri.ca','movri.ca'] CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ['DELETE','GET''POST','OPTIONS','PATCH','PUT'] CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['www.movri.ca','movri.ca','movri.ca'] CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [ 'accept', 'accept-encoding', 'authorization', 'content-type', 'dnt', 'origin', 'user-agent', 'x-csrftoken', 'x-requested-with' ] `